# How to use the same vendor package a of a dependency in golang?

Tags: go, vendor

I have a project, say `P`, depends on a library `L`, which in turn depends on a vendor library `V`.

Now `P` is also (directly) depends on `V`. Is it possible to tell the compiler just to use the `V` library in `L/vendor` ? Or else I must add `V` in `P/vendor` which i think is really redundant

Comment: You could create a symbolic link in your vendor folder. `ln -s ./vendor/src/P/vendor/V ./vendor/srv/V`

Comment: Library packages *should not vendor their dependencies*. It comes up over and over again. If a library is vendoring its dependencies, find a better library if you can.

Comment: @AlexEfimov: do not use symlinks inside GOPATH

Comment: @jayven: this isn't up to the compiler, its up to you to vendor the dependencies correctly. You should only have 1 vendor directory under your project, the tools used to manage the vendor directory are meant to handle that case.

Comment: @Adrian thx, since the library is using a non-standard fork, it needs some extra information

Comment: It's vendoring a fork? Whatever library that is, I would consider it unusable at that point. Best of luck, I hope you can work it out with some tooling.